Wave-particle duality?
What does it mean for an electron to behave as a wave? I can visualize electrons or other subatomic things as particles. But what do we mean when say it's all a wave. What is waving actually? Waves are just a way by which energy can get transferred right with the oscillation of particles. But in this case the particle is an electron and is it oscillating to produce waves? And then we say that normal day to day objects also have wave properties but not really significant. How can I visualize it?

Usually it means that in definite situations an electron behaves like a wave demonstrating for example interference and diffraction.

All electrons are in the EM field, the EM field is everywhere. The properties of the EM field (E and M are at 90 degrees, speed c, contains/transmits energy and forces) drive oscillatory behaviour of any particle that interacts with it. Similar to if you add energy to a piano string it oscillates.

A quantum particle IS a wave.But under special instances(wavefunction collapse) all of the wave gets concentrated in one region.

This might help - How can a red light photon be different from a blue light photon?

And this - In what medium are non-mechanical waves a disturbance? The aether?

@PhysicsDave Electrons would have wavelike properties even if they were uncharged and didn’t interact with the electromagnetic field, and even if the EM field didn’t exist.

@Ghoster To most of us if the EM field doesn't exist then electrons and positrons probably don't exist ...... if your correct then electrons must be interacting with some other field???

@PhysicsDave Matter waves have nothing to do with any kind of interactions. Non-interacting particles exhibit wave-particle duality.

@PhysicsDave To most of us if the EM field doesn't exist then electrons and positrons probably don't exist. In quantum field theory, electrons and positrons are quanta of a fermionic field; this field is not the bosonic EM field, which has photons as its quanta. These two fields happen to interact, but there is no reason that they have to, and there is no reason both have to exist.

Quantum mechanics is not a field theory so I dont understand why you brought up QFT.Wave particle duality exists for everything.For objects with large mass the wavelength is so small though.

What behaves like a wave is the quantum wave function
$$\Psi(\vec x_1, \dots, \vec x_n)$$
defined on configuration space. It evolves according to the Schrödinger equation
\begin{align}
\label{eq:S_eq}
i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(t, \vec x_1, \dots, \vec x_n) = - \sum_{i= 1}^n \frac{\hbar ^2}{2 m_i} \Delta_i  \Psi(t,\vec x_1, \dots, \vec x_n) + V(\vec x_1, \dots, \vec x_n)  \Psi(t, \vec x_1, \dots, \vec x_n)\,.
\end{align}
It must be stressed that this is not a classical wave like and EM-waves, as it is not defined on physical space. This creates a lot of confusion.
According to quantum mechanics, the electrons' positions are random with probability density
$$
\rho(\vec x_1, \dots, \vec x_1) = |\Psi(\vec x_1, \dots, \vec x_n)|^2.
$$
The waves are not produced by the particle.
As an example, consider the double-slit experiment with a single particle. In this case, it follows from the Schrödinger equation that $\rho(x)$ has the same interference pattern as a classical wave passing through the slit.
By doing many double-slit experiments in a row, we can sample the probability density $\rho$, i.e., the interference pattern builds up on the screen.
The similarity between this statistical pattern and the classical wave interference can be regarded as the wavelike behaviour of the particle.
On the other hand, the flashes on the screen in each individual run are sharply localized. This part of the phenomenology is rather similar to the behaviour of classical particles. Thus, we have also particle-like behaviour.
However, both the classical wave picture and the classical particle picture are wrong. Instead, we have a new theory called quantum mechanics that describes what is going on.
While the classical wave picture and the classical particle picture are incompatible, there is no such logical inconsistency with the quantum mechanics.

This is only the Copenhagen interpretation which is most likely not correct.

@Root Grooves You are absolutely correct. However, I didn't want to overcomplicate things. In my opinion the clearest picture of the "wave particle duality" is provided by Bohmian mechancis.

I personally dont like Bohmian mechanics because it breaks causality I like  objective-collapse theories.The Copenhagen interpretation doesnt provide a why on how the wavefunction collapse occurs.

Well, objective collapse theories are also good candidates. However, I don't know what you mean by breaking “causality”. If you mean locality, this is also violated in objective collapse theories and in any single world theory.

Yes sorry "locality".Bohmian mechanics requires a faster than light information exchange if im not mistaken.

Between the pilot wave and the particle.

@RootGroves Bohemian Mechanics BM doesn't require FTL.  I would say BM was never that fully developed but people inferred that nothing could happen before the creation of the photon which is incorrect.  The excited electron in the atom is already creating perturbations in the EM field even before photon emission. Many say there is no mystery in the DSE ... the EM field interferes and guides the dumb photon.  During all these QM discussions in the 1930s/1940s WWII broke out ... all the best scientists went to the nuclear age.  A lot of ancient academics wrote your high school textbook etc etc.
